# [ERROR][logstash.outputs.jdbc ] Unknown setting 'driver_library' for jdbc

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-jdbc

I want to Add My CSV File to postgreSQL.but whenever i try to connect it Show Error:
[ERROR][logstash.outputs.jdbc    ] Unknown setting 'driver_library' for jdbc
it is My Config.conf File

````
input {
  file {
    path => "C:/Users/Desktop/Input.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    codec => plain
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
    separator => ","
    columns => ["Column","Metric","Source_Table","Output_Column_Alias","Method"]
  }
}
output {
  jdbc {
    connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://hostname:5432/Database"
    username => "User"
    password => "Password"
    driver_library => "C:/Users/lib/postgresql-42.5.1.jar"
    driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
    statement => "INSERT INTO CSV_to_Postgresql (Column,Metric,Source_Table,Output_Column_Alias,Method) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Use [driver_jar_path](https://github.com/theangryangel/logstash-output-jdbc/blob/aea74f237cfda3b151dae29cf94b44123c2bc408/lib/logstash/outputs/jdbc.rb#L47), not driver_library. The elastic supported plugins use [jdbc_driver_library](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-integration-jdbc/blob/deeb4b2a92504ee739194681c10a140340365885/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc/jdbc.rb#L30) as the name of this option, but the jdbc output is a third party supported plugin which uses different conventions.